# For loop without initialization and conditions

Tags: c++, for-loop

I was going through this link of C++ Faq. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istreams-remember-bad-state.html

In the given program for loop ends after first iteration.

```
char name[1000];
int age;

for (;;) {
  std::cout << "Name: ";
  std::cin >> name;
  std::cout << "Age: ";
  std::cin >> age;
}
```

As explained numerical extractor leaves non-digit behind in input buffer. May be its something basic but can someone please explain how is for loop termination condition met??

Comment: `for (;;)` is an infinite loop, it requires `break` or `throw` to break the loop.

Comment: I don't think that loop ends after first iteration - at least, it doesn't for me.

Comment: The link states how to handle error with `std::cin`

Comment: "how is for loop termination condition met" - there is no such condition, ergo there is nothing to "meet".

Comment: Thanks all for explanation thought there is something strange that I am not able to get, but I was on right track.

Comment: Why not use `std::string` and `std::getline` so you don't have to hardcode the name length.

Answer (score 3):

`for (;;)` is an infinite loop, the same as `while(1)`, `while(true)`

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest re-reading the question in the link you posted.

> Why is my program ignoring my input request after the first iteration?

This clearly states that there is more than one iteration. The actual concern is that all iterations after the first one don't receive the expected values from cin. This is usually due to two main reasons:

1. The >> extractor left extra non-digits in the buffer. When you use the >> extractor, it discards all preceding whitespace, reads the characters it needs, then doesn't read any more characters (including whitespace). An example of this would be trying to read `15f` as an age. The 15 would be read, leaving the `f`. This value would then be read for the name.
2. The fail bit got set. In the example above, if there were no acceptable characters after the preceding whitespace, then a fail bit would be set. An example of this would be trying to read "f" as an age. This fail bit would be saved, and no future reads would be attempted until it is cleared.

For an example of the first problem, try typing a `15f` as the age and see what happens.

```
Name: Test
Age: 15f
name = Test, age = 15
Name: Age:
```

For a very clear example of the second problem, try typing a string for the age and see what happens. You'll end up with an infinite loop that doesn't wait for any more input.

```
Name: Test
Age: f
Name: Age: Name: Age: Name: Age: Name: Age: Name: ...
```

To fix these, all input up to (and including) the new line must be discarded. This is done using the std::cin.ignore method as demonstrated on the same page. If the fail bit was set, you'll also need to clear it using `std::cin.clear()`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining Ryan. Sorry my mistake missed the point been explained. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Chaks You're welcome. I explained it a little more, just in case it didn't make sense before.